# Android fastboot device-id

Tags: root-access

I have a smartphone lg g6 i try to root it.

When i put the command `adb devices` the cmd show me my attached device name.

I test many adb commands all works. Finally i put `adb reboot bootloader` and my phone was opened in fastboot mode.

All fastboot command works just the `fastboot oem` commands shows me this error:failed command.

I try also `fastboot oem devices-id` and show me the same error.
Note: fastboot devices work and show me my device name also `fastboot getvar all`, `fastboot oem unlock` all shows me result just `fastboot oem device-id` didn't work. Any idea please.

Edit: After i unlock my phone all the oem option they didn't work Any idea to relock my phone.

Comment: Not on every device bootloaders include `fastboot` protocol in its entirety. Particularly the `fatboot oem` commands are very OEMs/vendors specific. Even they vary for different devices from same manufacturer. So you need to find out right commands (if they exist) for your device. Check xda forums.

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-discover-hidden-fastboot-commands